# What color is this windows color?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, user-interface

I've been asked to replicate a WPF form, but I have no idea what color they are using. I've gotten the RGB of it as seen below, but I would rather find out what is the actual Windows color name.  I suspect it is indeed a default Windows color:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colour is approximately `Alice Blue`.

After converting it to hex it can be looked up http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/EFF3F7:

> #EFF3F7 (or 0xEFF3F7) is unknown color: *approx Alice Blue* - from the Color Information section

`Alice Blue` (#F0F8FF) itself is a Windows colour.

Comment: Is that a Windows Color? How did you find this so quickly?

Comment: The HEX doesn't match Alice blue. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx. Alice blue is: #FFF0F8FF

Answer (score 1):

I needed to convert a shade of Alice Blue as a background on a WPF form and found it took longer than expected to find the answer:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```

--

```
System.Drawing.Color myColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#EFF3F7");
this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(myColor.A, myColor.R, myColor.G, myColor.B));
```